# Doctrine : OneToOne entity relationship doesn't work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, entity

I'm working with php, and I have two entities Message and Post. The post is an attribute in the message entity and it's supposed to be a one to one unidirectional relation. But when I call message->getPost()->getText() in my controller I get this error message:

> Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\Test\monApplication\controller\mainController.php

The Message entity:

```
<?php

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="message")
 */
class message{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer")
     *  @GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="post", cascade={"persist"})
     * @JoinColumn(name="post", referencedColumnName ="id")
     */
    private $post;

    /** @Column(type="integer") */
    public $likes;

    public function getPost(){
        return $this->post;
    }
    public function getLikes(){
         return $this->likes;
    }
}

?>
```

The Post entity

```
<?php

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="post")
 */
class post{

    /** @Id @Column(type="integer")
     *  @GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=2000) */
    public $texte;

    /** @Column(type="string", length=200) */
    public $image;

    /** @Column(type="TIMESTAMP", length=4000) */
    public $date;
}

?>
```

My dbconnection class:

```
<?php

define ('HOST', 'localhost') ;
define ('USER', 'root'  ) ;
define ('PASS', '' ) ;
define ('DB', 'tp' ) ;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class dbconnection{

private static $instance=null, $entityManager;
private $error=null ;

private function __construct(){
    $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array("../../monApplication/model/"), true);

    $param = array(
    'dbname' => DB,
    'user'  => USER,
    'password' => PASS,
    'host'  => HOST,
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql');

    try{
        self::$entityManager = EntityManager::create($param, $config);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Probleme connexion base de données:".$e->getMessage();
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }

}

public static function getInstance(){
    if(self::$instance == null){
        self::$instance = new dbconnection();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function closeConnection(){
    self::$instance=null;
}

public function getEntityManager(){
    if(!empty(self::$entityManager))
        return self::$entityManager;
    else
        return NULL;
}


public function __clone(){

}

public function getError(){
    return $this->error;
}

}
```

My mainController:

```
<?php

class mainController
{

    public static function showMessage($request,$context){
        $messages = messageTable::getAllMessages();
        echo $message[0]->getPost()->text;   

        return context::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

And finally my project architecture is like this:

[image]

Comment: I can't see in your code where `$message->getPost()` is called? I expect this is in `mainController.php `, which you've not shown. Anyway, the cause of this is likey to be that a variable `$message` does not contain an object. Perhaps it is null?

Comment: I just added my mainController class to the question, the $message object isn't empty because the getLikes() works fine

Comment: That was just a mistyped character, I fixed it, but the problem isn't there

Comment: Well, this needs debugging, I guess. Is there anything in `$message[0]`? What type is it?

Comment: It's a message obj, I can access its likes atrribute but i can't acess the post

Comment: Try var_dump($message[0]->getPost()). Do you get an entity? Probably the relation does not exist or not correctly set.

Comment: I don't see namespaces and use directives in the provided code. Please make sure that you use correct namespaces and include correct classes.

Comment: Is the join column on your message table called "post" or possibly "post_id"? try to run the validate command https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/tools.html#runtime-vs-development-mapping-validation and check for errors in your schema.

Answer (score 7):

Try to change

```
private $post;
```

to

```
public $post;
```

(and you should use protected vars)

You have 2 others problems :

```
/** @Column(type="string", length=2000) */
public $texte;
```

Should be :

```
/** @Column(type="text") */
public $texte;
```

Because string is limited to 255 caracters length.

And your property is "texte" so you should have

```
echo $message[0]->getPost()->texte;
```

instead of

```
echo $message[0]->getPost()->text;
```

Answer (score 4):

first thing i would suggest to debug as you didn't mention it (no reference to messageTable)

```
messageTable::getAllMessages();
```

using var_dump() or [dump()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) to see the type, and check if it returns data, then decide how you will access to the first message.

secondly, notice there is no $message variable, there is $messages (the s in the end).

also, there is not ->text, there is ->texte

then, fix the  context::SUCCESS to $context::SUCCESS

and lastly, there would be more errors luckily, but hey, var_dump() would be your friend, so make use of it !